# What is the difference between "and" and "with"?

Tags: conjunctions

Do these two sentences express the same thought?

```
I go to the movie with you.
You and I go to the movie.
```

When would you choose one over the other?

Comment: Neither.  I'd say "we go to the movie together".

Comment: Asking _What is the difference between "and" and "with"?_ is like asking _What is the difference between an elephant and an onion?_ "With" is a _preposition,_ while "and" is a _conjunction._

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to replace the pronouns with people names A and B because it's easier for me to explain what's going on this way.

> A goes to the movie with B.

This means either A goes, with B as a companion, or B goes, with A as a companion.

> A and B go to the movie.

This means A goes, and B goes.  They might or might not sit together.

I could be more helpful if you provided more context.  Also, the simple present tense makes the sentences feel contrived (unnatural).  It would be easier to work with past tense, or continuous-as-future.